# Python Selenium: get values from dropdown list

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium in Python to open a web page and I'm trying to get the list of values from a specific dropdown list. Let's say the HTML code for the dropdown list looks like this:

```
<select class="mdc-select__input" name="nouveau-num" data-msisdn-loaded="0">                           <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                     <option value="351 8320175">351 8320175</option>
<option value="351 8652736">351 8652736</option>
<option value="351 8783295">351 8783295</option>
<option value="351 8094085">351 8094085</option>
<option value="351 8861691">351 8861691</option>
<option value="351 8271705">351 8271705</option>
<option value="351 8970191">351 8970191</option>
<option value="351 8965848">351 8965848</option>
<option value="351 8353924">351 8353924</option>
<option value="351 8988158">351 8988158</option>
</select>
```

And I want to retrieve all the values between `<option>` tags. I tried to do a `browser.page_source` which returns the HTML source of the web page and then do a regular expression (something like `<option value="[0-9 ]*">`) but the result is empty. For some reason however, the HTML code above is not in the HTML page source code retrieved by Selenium. Any ideas how I can approach this differently/what is wrong with the current approach?

Comment: If you ready to use Ruby, then this would be one line of code `puts b.select_list(name: "nouveau-num").options.map{|option| option.text}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `Select` object and iterate over the amount of options with a loop.

For example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
selector = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("nouveau-num"))
options = selector.options
for index in range(0, len(options)-1):
    print(options[index])
```

#### Edit:

I tried the code on the link you provided and there seems to be a delay until the dropdown's values are loaded. In addition I forgot that options has a list of elements so you need to specify .text. On top of all that `By.NAME` seems to work better than `find_element_by_name`

Here is the corrected code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

dropdown = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "nouveau-num")

selector = Select(dropdown)

# Waiting for the values to load
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 
10).until(EC.element_to_be_selected(selector.options[0]))

options = selector.options
for index in range(1, len(options)-1):
    print(options[index].text)
```

Using this code I receive the following results:

```
351 8631174
351 8586821
351 8014561
351 8831839
351 8957001
351 8673968
351 8612034
351 8585995
351 8438130
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it's not working. The website I'm using is https://registrazione.iliad.it/ and I first click the "no" radio button, after which the dropdown menu appears from which I want to extract the values.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/#answer-1732454) parsing HTML with Regex is never a good idea.

You better use [`find_elements_by_css_selector`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector) or [`find_elements_by_xpath`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath).

Example with css selectors:

```
for tag in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('select[name=nouveau-num] option'):
    value = tag.get_attribute('value')
    text = tag.text
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it's not working. The website I'm using is https://registrazione.iliad.it/ and I first click the "no" radio button, after which the dropdown menu appears from which I want to extract the values.

Answer (score 0):

for this i do:

1. Get the xpath. `(//label/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1])`
2. Put `"/*"` at the end `(//label/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/*)`
3. Find it with driver.find_elements (This is important, if you ommit the "s" of the end it will fail) `(lista = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//label/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/*'))`
4. then, you will get a list of web elements (not of strings), i called it "lista"
5. use a for loop and put the values into a list.

   listaItems = list()

   for i in listaItems:
   listaItems.appeend(i.text)

And thats all.

Answer (score 0):

```
def verify_dropdown_value(self, Elementlocator, LocatorType, Expectedvalue):
    time.sleep(5)
    Value = self.helper.identify_element(Elementlocator, LocatorType, "Value")
    #ActualValue = Value.get_attribute('value')

    #options = Value.options
    ActualValue = Value.text

    if ActualValue == Expectedvalue:
        print("Pass")
        return True
    else:
        print("Fail")
        return False
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).